# Cant access sqlite database (dbfile) in pad device while the same works fine in flash builder Simulator

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ipad, sqlite, flash-builder

I have developed an application in flash builder 4.5 for ipad device which retrieves data from database ie sqlite the path for simulator to access the database was File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("assets/xyz.db");
However when i tested on  simultor everything was wotking (application) fine.But when i launched the same application on ipad it is not retrieving neither inserting data can you please me so as to find what may be the problem 
Plz help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`documentDirectory` is not supported on iOS devices. Use the `applicationDirecty`instead, that works for both Android and iOS devices.

Comment: Thanks a  lot for the help @Al_Birdy.it just wrked!!

Comment: how to store data in .db file in ios which directory to use?

Comment: FYI: in iOS you are not allowed to modify files in applicationDirecty, if you will need to UPDATE or INSERT some rows in database better to use applicationStorageDirecty to store database file